# "Undefined inverse geodesic" when plotting line with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, inverse, valueerror

This is the sample code I'm using right now : https://python-graph-gallery.com/300-draw-a-connection-line/

And it works fine when I use the sample coordinates, and it plots an orange line like in the example.

However, when I'm inputting my own coordinates instead of the sample ones, it produces a ValueError.

This is how my code looks :

```
m=Basemap()

m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#A6CAE0', linewidth=0)
m.fillcontinents(color='grey', alpha=0.7, lake_color='grey')
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.1, color="white")

# Add a connection between new york and London
startlat = 40.78; startlon = -73.98
arrlat = 51.53; arrlon = 0.08

m.drawgreatcircle(59.33, 18.07, 35.3, 149.1, linewidth=2, color='orange')
```

This is the entire error it produces :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-b3f6087641a6> in <module>()
     14 print(end)
     15 m.drawgreatcircle(startlon,startlat,arrlon,arrlat, linewidth=4, color='orange')
---> 16 m.drawgreatcircle(59.33, 18.07, 35.3, 149.1, linewidth=2, color='orange')

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\LocalEnv\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py in drawgreatcircle(self, lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2, del_s, **kwargs)
   2875         # use great circle formula for a perfect sphere.
   2876         gc = pyproj.Geod(a=self.rmajor,b=self.rminor)
-> 2877         az12,az21,dist = gc.inv(lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2)
   2878         npoints = int((dist+0.5*1000.*del_s)/(1000.*del_s))
   2879         lonlats = gc.npts(lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2,npoints)

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\LocalEnv\lib\site-packages\pyproj\__init__.py in inv(self, lons1, lats1, lons2, lats2, radians)
    826         inz, zisfloat, zislist, zistuple = _copytobuffer(lons2)
    827         ind, disfloat, dislist, distuple = _copytobuffer(lats2)
--> 828         _proj.Geod._inv(self,inx,iny,inz,ind,radians=radians)
    829         # if inputs were lists, tuples or floats, convert back.
    830         outx = _convertback(xisfloat,xislist,xistuple,inx)

_proj.pyx in _proj.Geod._inv (_proj.c:5471)()

ValueError: undefined inverse geodesic (may be an antipodal point)
```

Does anyone see what the problem is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Function usage: `drawgreatcircle(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2)`. You have lat2=149.1 which is invalid.

Comment: Your answer made me think of how I supplied the input, and in the function where I was getting the coordinates returned them as lat/lon, causing the error. Thanks for the help!